# Rails / jQuery AJAX not succeeding

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails application where I have some ajax calls, it usally works just fine, but this one I can get working:

I tried running the rails class from the browser, works fine, and I tried calling an alert with the params just before the ajax call, works fine.. but no connection, whats wrong?

jQuery:

```
   $.ajax({
  url: "things/ajax_text_read",
  data: "book_id=" + book_id  + "&page_number=" + page_number  + "&type="+ type,
  success: function(){$(this).text('data'); }
});
```

Rails:

```
    def ajax_text_read
@book_id = params['book_id']
@page_number = params['page_number']  
@type = params['type']

@text = Thing.where(:parent_id => @page_number, :book => @book_id, :media_type => 'text')  

if(@type=='description')
render :inline => "<%= @text[0].description %>" 
else
render :inline => "<%= @text[0].title %>" 
end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that `things/ajax_text_read` is a valid uri :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "things/ajax_text_read",
  data: "book_id=" + book_id  + "&page_number=" + page_number  + "&type="+ type,
  success: $.proxy(function(data){
      $(this).text(data);
  }, this)
});
```

Comment: I solved it, apparently I can't use $(this) inside an ajax request while inside a loop  : )

Comment: @jakobk haven't noticed that, you're "right". You can however use it if you use `$.proxy` with `$.ajax`.

Comment: I used the ajax request inside an each loop, if I put a parameter with the each loop, and use that parameter later it works fine. Will the proxy function make sure that I am always getting the latest selector / key ?

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(){$(this).text('data'); }
```

doesn't make much sense. $(this) in this context is going to be the success function, and you're trying to set its text content to the word 'data'?

Perhaps you mean this:

```
success: function(data) { $('#something_in_your_page').text(data); }
```

instead.

Comment: True, typo.. but still if I use an alert,nothing happens